# svn on Mac only checkout works, but cannot commit or import

Tags: xcode, macos, svn

We have a repository set up in windows server 2008. And from my macbook pro which runs osx lion, I can checkout projects using xcode or command line. 
But When I try to commit(or import) a project or files I get an error:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File not found: transaction '135-4r', path '/..../trunk/....m'
```

Same error when I use command line.
Please help

**Edit**
Everything works from a windows computer.

Comment: Does it work form a Windows box?  It looks to me like it's a server side problem rather than client side.  The transaction it's talking about is the new revision being built on the server.  It could be your antivirus solution getting in the way.  Many antivirus solutions on Window interfere with file-related system APIs and often break some file system semantics. :-(

Comment: Thanks @jszakmeister, it works from a windows computer. I'll try to disable the firewall or antivirus program.

Comment: That's interesting that it works from a Windows computer. :-(  Maybe it doesn't work all the time though (issues with antivirus can be racy).  I did double-check the Subversion source code.  The error is coming from the server side though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake. The parent folder we created in the server side had a name with space " " in it. When I try to commit files from Mac, the address became "http ://...../folder%20name/...." I re-created a folder now it's working

Comment: Any idea on other workarounds? This same issue just came up for me on a large pre-existing project and it isn't really viable to just rename 30 folders.

Comment: @bplattenburg try to place space within a quotation mark, like " "

Comment: @SamChen i am using svn commit filepath -m "message" to commit in my svn repository but changes are not reflecting in svn repo..can u tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @jayantrawat this is a different question so I suggest you create a new thread. Not an expert on svn sorry.